# Performance function calls per frame

Tags: c++, performance

I'm a game developer therefore performance is really important to me.
My simple question:

I have a lot of checks(button clicks,collisions,whatever) running per frame, but I don't want to put everything in one function, therefore I would split them into other functions and just call them:

```
void Tick()
{
 //Check 1 ..... lots of code
 //Check 2 ...... lots of code
 //Check 3 ..... lots of code
}
```

to

```
void Tick()
{
 funcCheck1();
 funcCheck2();
 funcCheck3();
}

void funcCheck1()
{
 //check1 lots of code
}
void funcCheck2()
{
 //check2 lots of code
}
void funcCheck3()
{
 //check3 lots of code
}
```

Does the function call per frame has any performance impact?(not inlined)
Clearly the second version is much more readable.

Comment: Why don't you profile and find out?

Comment: The overhead of calling a function, over the work in the function, can be substantial if the function is REALLY trivial, but in most cases it's not. The only way to REALLY find out, however, is to measure the difference. I always start off with the assumption that function calls are "free", and if profiling later tells me they are a problem, make sure they inline in some way or another.

Comment: If you want numbers, measure.

Comment: And measure it with real compiler configuration like release mode, optimization enabled etc. . I made this mistake more than one not to look onto the real optimized application.

Comment: If performance was important to you, you'd know that microoptimizations are dumb. Right now you're just guessing.

Comment: As above, profile.  That said - given the "lots of code" per function, and assuming even a few percent of that need to be run then the call overhead becomes a small percentage of the overall time.  That's distinct from the relatively rare case of say a function hosting a single huge switch with each case being a "cheap" statement or two (e.g. `a += 2;`), where the call overhead may dominate the execution time.  Anyway, why do you say "not inlined"?  Are you going to actively avoid inlining?

Comment: hmm i'll test it now

Comment: even if the function is empty, it as an function call overhead :o

Comment: recently I've splittet a large function into 10~ smaller function additionally to a lot of other checks per frame, seems like i should only split them into 2-3 for better readability, because on old mobile devices this could cause problems

Answer (score 0):

If you don't pass any complex objects by value, the overhead of calling several functions instead of putting all code in one function should be negligible (e.g.
put function parameters on top of the stack, add space for the return type, jump to the beginning of the called function's code)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot say for sure, specifically that the compiler could inline small function automatically. The only way to be sure is to use a profiler and compare the two scenarios.

Comment: even if the function is empty it has an small overhead x.x
in release optimization

Comment: Yes but its is a matter of tradeoff. as a general rule, the performance of a good object oriented application design is bad. For the sake of optimization you have to break good design rules (boost's intrusive library is a good example).


So is it worth it to break good design rules to gain some milliseconds for a function that is already taking hundreds of milliseconds to execute?  


For more on the topic of the pitfalls of object oriented design see this presentation: http://research.scee.net/files/presentations/gcapaustralia09/Pitfalls_of_Object_Oriented_Programming_GCAP_09.pdf

Comment: ofc it's good for better readability etc.,but splitting a function in too many unnecessary small functions, could cause performance impact, especially on old mobile devices. (i think?)